# iOS App launch showing blank black screen for few seconds

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios4, ios6

I am not using the "Default.png" files for Splash Screen for my App. When I launch my App it is showing black screen for few seconds(Ex: 4 to 5 seconds) and showing the initial screen.

During App launch I want to see initial view-controller UI without the black screen.

How can I fix this?

Please help

Comment: You have to add Default.png as launch image in project to avoid this black screen.

Comment: take and screenshot of your homepage and make that `Default.png` and add to the project.

Comment: Even if we have a default image, it shows the black screen and then the default image.

Answer (score 0):

Create Splash Screen on another storyboard named LaunchScreen.storyboard and in Your Project --> General Tab, select Launch Screen File to LaunchScreen

Hope this will help :-)

Answer (score -3):

You need to set windows background color to white color or color of your choice

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
return YES;
}
```

Comment: This thing doesn't work for the initial black screen.